# Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and got the "Oh no, something has gone wrong" when trying to log in

Tags: upgrade, login

First off, I'm a newbie and I started to dislike Apple's business plan so much I decided to give Linux a whirl.

I've been running a brand new desktop with Ubuntu 18.04 for about a year and a half and have gotten along fairly well.

It asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 20.04 and I did.  Only thing it asked during the download was if I wanted to keep some files referencing gnome.  I had a fairly customized desktop so I said "keep".  The download all seemed to go fine until I tried to log in.  I input my password and it takes me to the white "oh no, something has gone wrong" page.

The thing that might help diagnose this is that I have a guest account which I created and it is "stock", meaning left with default settings.  I'm able to sign in using it, which is how I'm writing this question.

It made sense to me that it could be a gnome problem given the question during download and that the stock account can still log in, so I tried this which didn't change things:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get remove gnome-session gnome gnome-shell
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

I also have run the line which returned:
"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded" which I assumed might return an error but it says everything is up to date.

I'm trying to not lose my data, which I assume is just hiding behind door number one but I can't login.  As a last ditch, I've thought about using the guest account and trying to make it's home folder point to the home folder of the locked account instead?  But I'd much rather figure out the actual problem with logging in and I'm a bit leery doing much more coding without knowing what I'm doing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and remember I'm a newbie so I'll have to be walked through anything fairly childishly.

Comment: Where were the files located that you were asked to keep/replace?   Most packages don't include user setup files (which will be in your $HOME directory and not a system directory).  I suspect that's your issue (still a guess). What files were they? as that's the clue as to packages that maybe need `dpkg-reconfigure` (ie. you to get asked the question again).. You can re-install without erasing data (but backups should always be performed, a check-box is easily missed or like mistake made)

Comment: Were you using a virtual terminal (ctrl-alt F3 and text login) to run the sudo commands?  The guest account typically does not have sudo access.

Comment: ubfan1 if I wasn't in the (ctrl+alt F3) terminal before, I tried again in that terminal and nothing changed.

Comment: guiverc, I don't know where the files were located it asked me about, I just know they had to do with gnome.  Are you saying that reinstalling might do the trick?  I'd gladly answer "don't keep" if asked that question again.  What would be the proper method to reinstall while also retaining my data?  And I know I should have backed stuff up, but you live and you learn and although I'd really like my data back, I won't be brought to tears if I lose it all.  But I do greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to reset your Gnome config to default. Here's how you can do it.

Open a terminal and:

```
cd /home/{your directory}
mkdir .gnome-config-bak
mv .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache \
.dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails .config/dconf/user \
.compiz* .gnome-config-bak/
```

Be sure to replace `{your directory}` with whatever your home directory name is.

Then remove the `user` file:

```
rm -f .config/dconf/user
```

Alternatively, you can just rename it to something like `user.bak`.

From here you should be able to log into your primary account again, though your desktop will be reset to default. You *may* be able to copy some of the previously moved files back to their proper locations to restore past functionality, but it would probably be better to use these as a template to re-install and reconfigure.

Hope this gets you back into your account.

Comment: a couple of the files you listed to move don't exist on my computer, and others say I don't have permission to move them.  Does that mean I need to move them using "sudo mv"?  And if some of those files don't exist, will those commands have then not have the same outcome for me?

Comment: If the files do not exist, there's no need to do anything with them. The others will need `sudo`, though, as you're moving files owned by another account, which is generally a no-no.

Comment: I gave it a go with sudo but it didn't seem to change the login.  I appreciate the help though.